# Keycloak multiple authentication flows for one client

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, keycloak

I have a spring boot server and need two login screens. One for mobile and one for browser usage. For mobile i created a custom spi authenticator with some aditional loginc. Now i want to be redirected to the normal login (browser authentication flow) whenever i enter the site. But when calling e.g. /mobile/login i want to be redirected to my mobile authentication flow. Is this possible?

Comment: it was not possible ... but i created my a custom authentication that could handle both mobile and desktop logins

Comment: Couldn't you just use two different clients for that?